# How to put a breakpoint on the current line withtout typing the line number in the Python pdb debugger?

Tags: python, pdb

I'm used to GDB, where `b` does that.

But in `pdb`, `b` [just list breakpoints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).

I can do `b 123`, but lazy to type `123`.

Maybe a magic argument like `b .`?

I know PyCharm and `__import__('pdb').set_trace()`, just checking if there is an usable CLI alternative for those quick debugs.

Comment: Is there not an ide you could use? You wouldn't need to type at all to set a breakpoint then

Comment: @Sayse sure, I know PyCharm. Just wondering about the CLI.

Comment: what about adding a custom command to pdb? otherwise, it is hard to get the current line number.

Comment: @georgexsh if you have a good suggestion how to do that, create an answer :-)

Comment: @georgexsh hey, I had upvoted your post.

Answer (score 3):

if you accept adding a new `pdb` command, it is trivial:

```
def do_breakcurrent(self, arg):
    cur_lineno = str(self.curframe.f_lineno)
    return self.do_break(cur_lineno)


import pdb
pdb.Pdb.do_breakcurrent = pdb.Pdb.do_bc = do_breakcurrent
```

use `breakcurrent` or `bc`:

```
(Pdb) bc
Breakpoint 1 at /Users/georgexsh/workspace/so/52110534.py:11
```

if you want to put those code into `.pdbrc` to make it available automatically, need little tweak:

```
import pdb
pdb.Pdb.do_bc = lambda self,arg: self.do_break(str(self.curframe.f_lineno))
```